# How to change a specific element inside a ListView on creation

Tags: java, android, listview

Assume I have a `ListView` of elements and I would like to change the background color of the first element in this ListView, not by `setOnItemClickListener`, but on the ListView creation.

I have tried the following:

```java
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View root = inflater. Inflate(R.layout.fragment_manage, container, false);

    listView = root.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(root.getContext(), R.layout.list_item, R.id.listNameTextView, elementList);
    listView.setAdapter(listArrayAdapter);

    // Am trying to change the element here.
    listView.getChildAt(listView.getFirstVisiblePosition()).setBackgroundColor(000);

    return root;
}
```

But I get a NullPointerException.

```java
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setBackgroundColor(int)' on a null object reference
```

How would I go about accessing the list element and changing it otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

you can do that in getView method at your adapter and if you use ArrayAdapter you can also override getView method as following :

```
     ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,strings){
                @Override
                public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                    View view;
                    if(convertView==null) {
                        LayoutInflater Inflater = (LayoutInflater) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(MainActivity.this.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                        view = Inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        view=convertView;
                    }
                    if(position==YOUR_TARGET_POSITION_TO_CHANGE_ITS_BACKGROUND)
                    {
                        view.setBackgroundColor(0x2196f3);
                    }
//Update Of textView

                    TextView txt1=(TextView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
                text1.setText(strings[position]);

    //Rest of your code
                    return view;
                }
            };
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```